# Move row to top in data table c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a data table in which if the Addresses match move one of the rows to the top of the data table. I am using the following code but it doesnt work. Any idea how to achieve this. The data in the data table is imported from an excel file. I have tried the same if statement in GridView to highlight the duplicates and that works but I also want to move them to the top because the data has more than 1000 rows and its hard to move up and down again and again to check for the highlighted row.

```
for (int row = 1; row < dtf1.Rows.Count; row++)
{
    for (int rowinner = 1; rowinner < dtf1.Rows.Count; rowinner++)
    {
        if (rowinner != row)
        {
            if (dtf1.Rows[row][addresscolno] == dtf1.Rows[rowinner][addresscolno].ToString())
            {
                DataRow newrow = dtf1.Rows[row];
                dtf1.Rows.RemoveAt(row);
                dtf1.AcceptChanges();
                dtf1.Rows.InsertAt(newrow, 1);
                dtf1.AcceptChanges();
                GridView1.DataSource = dtf1;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So basically you want to _order_ the DataRows?!

Answer (score 1):

So you want to reorder the `DataTable`. The row with a given address should be on the top. You can use `Linq-To-DataSet` to order the rows and `CopyToDataTable` to create a new `DataTable` with the new order:

```
// assuming the address is a string in a variable address, to simplify matters
DataTable tblOrdered = dtf1.AsEnumerable()
    .OrderByDescending(r => r.Field<string>("addresscolno") == address)
    .ThenBy(r => r.Field<string>("addresscolno"))
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Then you can use that as DataSource for your GridView.

**Edit**: Give also [`DataTable.Rows.InsertAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.datarowcollection.insertat%28v=vs.100%29) a try.

```
dtf1.Rows.InsertAt(dtf1.Rows[rowinner], 0);
```

Comment: I want to compare all the rows one by one and if the addresses match then move both rows to the top.

Comment: `dtf1.AsEnumerable()` yields DataRows of the DataTable. Therefor `r`  is the DataRow. You can omit the `ThenBy` if you only want to ensure that the address matches are on top and the order of the other rows doesn't matter. Here the address-matches are first followed by  the other rows orderd by  address.

Comment: how do I edit the above code to compare two rows and then move the row ?

Comment: @A.J: I don't understand, the above code compares the rows and will order them so that the address-matches will be first.

Comment: Yes true, if the row matches move both to the top of the table. Is this somehow possible ?

Comment: @A.J: The above code will do this exactly. Ok, it'll create a new DataTable with that order but... Have you tested it?

Comment: address value is equal to duplicate address ?

Comment: I am not sure what to put in the address variable.

Comment: @A.J.: It's not clear from your question what youz're actually trying to achieve. So i've used a variable as placeholder for _what you're searching_. That will be on top after the `OrderBy`. So you should edit your question to provide more informations(what is `rowinner`, `addresscolno`, ...).